# Stored procedure to UPDATE row to "closest" match in one table from data in another table

Tags: sql-server, update

I have a table called `ThawLaneA` that has a populated column `ThawTime` that has DATETIME value. The first row starts at a specific time, and each row from there "increases" by a specific amount of time (four minutes in this example).

I have another table called `PackingLineA`.  It contains `ThawTime` as well.  I need to find the closest time down to the seconds and UPDATE the `ThawLaneA` table with the `PackLineA.RackID`, `LoinMaterialNumber` WHERE `ThawLaneA.RackID` IS NULL.  IF NOT NULL then it would "move" to the "next closest" row.

This is the relevant CREATE TABLE script...

```
USE [ThawScheduler]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PackingLineA]    Script Date: 4/3/2019 12:55:39 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PackingLineA](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RackID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LoinMaterialNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ThawTime] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ThawLaneA]    Script Date: 4/3/2019 12:55:39 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ThawLaneA](
    [ThawID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ThawTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ThwRackID] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [LoinMaterialNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[PackingLineA] ON 
GO
```

...and some sample data:

```
INSERT [dbo].[PackingLineA] ([ID], [RackID], [LoinMaterialNumber], [ThawTime]) VALUES (1, N'A1R1', N'100240', CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:15:57.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PackingLineA] ([ID], [RackID], [LoinMaterialNumber], [ThawTime]) VALUES (2, N'A2R1', N'100240', CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:20:50.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PackingLineA] ([ID], [RackID], [LoinMaterialNumber], [ThawTime]) VALUES (3, N'A3R1', N'100240', CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:25:43.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PackingLineA] ([ID], [RackID], [LoinMaterialNumber], [ThawTime]) VALUES (4, N'A1R2', N'100240', CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:30:36.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PackingLineA] ([ID], [RackID], [LoinMaterialNumber], [ThawTime]) VALUES (5, N'A2R2', N'100240', CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:35:29.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PackingLineA] ([ID], [RackID], [LoinMaterialNumber], [ThawTime]) VALUES (6, N'A3R2', N'100240', CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:40:22.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PackingLineA] ([ID], [RackID], [LoinMaterialNumber], [ThawTime]) VALUES (7, N'A1R3', N'100240', CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:45:15.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PackingLineA] ([ID], [RackID], [LoinMaterialNumber], [ThawTime]) VALUES (8, N'A2R3', N'100240', CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:50:08.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PackingLineA] ([ID], [RackID], [LoinMaterialNumber], [ThawTime]) VALUES (9, N'A3R3', N'100240', CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:55:01.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[PackingLineA] ([ID], [RackID], [LoinMaterialNumber], [ThawTime]) VALUES (10, N'A1R4', N'100240', CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:59:54.000' AS DateTime))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[PackingLineA] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2019-04-02T23:59:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:03:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:07:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:11:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:15:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (6, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:19:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (7, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:23:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (8, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:27:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (9, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:31:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (10, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:35:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (11, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:39:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (12, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:43:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (13, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:47:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (14, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:51:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (15, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:55:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (16, CAST(N'2019-04-03T00:59:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (17, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:03:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (18, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:07:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (19, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:11:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (20, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:15:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (21, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:19:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (22, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:23:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (23, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:27:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (24, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:31:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (25, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:35:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (26, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:39:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (27, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:43:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (28, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:47:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (29, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:51:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (30, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:55:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] ([ThawID], [ThawTime], [ThwRackID], [LoinMaterialNumber]) VALUES (31, CAST(N'2019-04-03T01:59:02.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ThawLaneA] OFF
GO
```

This is what the first couple of rows that would get data would look like:

```
+----+--------+--------------------+---------------------+--+
| ID | RackID | LoinMaterialNumber |      ThawTime       |  |
+----+--------+--------------------+---------------------+--+
| 20 | A1R1   | 100240             | 2019-04-03 01:15:02 |  |
| 21 | A2R1   | 100240             | 2019-04-03 01:19:02 |  |
| 22 | NULL   | NULL               | 2019-04-03 01:23:02 |  |
| 23 | A3R1   | 100240             | 2019-04-03 01:27:02 |  |
+----+--------+--------------------+---------------------+--+
```